# TCP/IP protocol: intercepting remote packets on the internet

Tags: tcp, ip

Say somebody is in Sydney, AU and wants to capture TCP/IP packets from the internet in San Jose, US. Is there a way to do that ? I suppose they would need to tunnel through a VPN first, but would then it need to even be one in San Jose, or would any in San Francisco do ?

Also, say for arguments sake, hypothetically they wanted to capture packets for specific sites like face-book, to perhaps prove that RSA is uncrackable. Especially maybe for engineers logging into the face-book data centre from outside. How would they do that ? TIA

Unrelated (for side discussion), but does anyone else think it ironic that some of the most evil places are now named after saints ? Hmmm...

Comment: This question is not related to programming, i.e. off-topic here. It might be better suited for [security.se]. But in short: in order to sniff traffic you have to be present where the traffic is. This means either you have access to network equipment in the normal path of the traffic (like by hacking these systems) or you are able to reroute the traffic through equipment in your control (like with BGP hijacking).

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I've no reason to doubt the veracity of your answer so I'll mark it as correct if you want to make it the official answer. I don't know if moderators can move this thread to its proper place.